# Cut Shape into an Image / other Elements

Tags: html, css

[image]

Ive got a Grid with 6 planets. To let them appear a little bit more interesting, I wanted to cut out a tri-angle shape in the middle of each image. Something like that:

[image]

Is there a way to (easily) do it?. Maybe even being able to animate that tri-angle a little bit on :hover

Comment: What has the question to do with `css-animation` or `javascript`? You might looking for `clip-path`. It would be the easiest solution. PS: To not tag in title, thats what you have the tags for!

Answer (score 1):

Just use `clip-path` to clip away that tri-angle from the picture. You can use `css-animation` to clip aswell:

```css
img {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 20% 0, 50% 40%, 80% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200.jpg/FF0000">
```